# Single line command for MOVE preserving the same folder structure

Tags: macos, command-line, bash, file-transfer

I've found many solutions for this problem already, but all them copying and after removing the files. I need a single command who move or copy and remove file by file.

I'm not too deep in command line so I could manage this below but I'm not sure how to remove after copy.

```
find . -name "*.extension" -exec cp --parent {} ../NewFolder/ \;
```

Using OSX. Thanks.

Comment: instead of just copying in your exec, do two things with `"cp ..... && rm {} \;"`

Comment: I'm presuming you can't just use `mv`....

Comment: You're right! Post it as an answer pls!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of just copying in your exec, do two things with `"cp ..... && rm {} \;"`

`&&` in bash means 'Run this command next, only if the previous command exited successfully (with a error code of 0)

Comment: not "or lower", exactly 0

Comment: @glennjackman ty, fixing. Wasn't sure.

Answer (score 1):

To mimic `cp --parents`, you need to use `mkdir` and `mv` together.

```
find . -name "*.extension" -exec sh -c 'dir=../NewFolder/$(dirname "{}"); mkdir -p "$dir" && mv -v "{}" "$dir"' \;
```

---

Verbose console cut'n'paste:

```
$ tree source
source
└── a
    ├── b
    │   ├── b.extension
    │   ├── c
    │   │   └── c.extension
    │   └── d
    └── e
        └── f
            └── f.extension

6 directories, 3 files
$ tree dest
dest

0 directories, 0 files
$ cd source
$ find . -name "*.extension" -exec sh -c 'dir=../dest/$(dirname "{}"); mkdir -p "$dir" && mv -v "{}" "$dir"' \;
'./a/e/f/f.extension' -> '../dest/./a/e/f/f.extension'
'./a/b/c/c.extension' -> '../dest/./a/b/c/c.extension'
'./a/b/b.extension' -> '../dest/./a/b/b.extension'
$ cd ..
$ tree source
source
└── a
    ├── b
    │   ├── c
    │   └── d
    └── e
        └── f

6 directories, 0 files
$ tree dest
dest
└── a
    ├── b
    │   ├── b.extension
    │   └── c
    │       └── c.extension
    └── e
        └── f
            └── f.extension

5 directories, 3 files
```